# Can not change _TOP target on links in reports from SharePoint 2013 / SSRS ( GO TO URL )

Tags: iframe, sharepoint, reporting-services

We have SharePoint 2013 with Reporting Service add on.

We have ERP that can run SSRS reports in an IFRAME.

The ERP dns is ERP.OURDOMAIN.COM and SharePoint is SP.OURDOMAIN.COM

I have reports that has Go To URL Action to ERP.

Problem is that we need to open the link in a new window or into the IFRAME.

This would work with TARGET=_BLANK or eg. TARGET=_erpIFrame.

The problem is that for some reason SSRS adds TARGET="_TOP" to the Go To URL.

I tried to use javascript to open the link eg.

```
    javascript:void(window.open('http://erp.ourdomain.com/default.aspx?ProjectCode=12345','_blank'))
```

The link works fine when I run it directly from the SharePoint 2013 report library.

But when report runs inside IFRAME in ERP server the link does not work at all.

When I click on the link nothing happens.

I do not know if it is the IFRAME and domain names that causes some IE11 security blocking. Or the fact that the link in HTML source looks like :

```
    <a tabindex="1" class="A45592b6319f04852ae690abb779bfb4393a" href="javascript:void(window.open('http://erp.ourdomain.com/default.aspx?ProjectCode=12345','_blank'))" target="_top">12345</a>
```

Note that the last target="_top" is added by SSRS and I can not find any way to tell SSRS not to add it.

If I use a normal link http://erp.ourdomain.com/default.aspx?ProjectCode=12345 the link opens in _TOP and removes ERP navigation.

I also have tried adding target='_blank' in the report URL eg.

```
    http://sp.ourdomain.com/_layouts/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rc:LinkTarget=_blank&rv:RelativeReportUrl=/Reports/report.rdl
```

Or

```
    http://sp.ourdomain.com/_layouts/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/Reports/report.rdl&rc:LinkTarget=_blank
```

But when I check the HTML source code on the report the link always has target="_top"

So the rc:LinkTarget has no effect.

Please help, is there no way to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

I got the rc:LinkTarget= working. It does not work after the report url if opened from sharepoint. But it does work if I use the reportserver URL.